# converting Html to Json with Python

Tags: python, html, json

'I'm trying to find a way to convert HTML to JSON with Python, and I can't find a simple way, just ways to build it myself which does not make sense in huge HTML.
can you help me?
i tried use chat gpt but it didn't help so this is my last option '

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].

Comment: Do you really want to convert a page of html to json or do you want to convert an html table to json or do you want to download a web response that is already json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building an HTML to JSON converter yourself, use an existing one, like [`html-to-json`](https://pypi.org/project/html-to-json/).

Once installed with `pip install html-to-json`, add this to your code:

```py
import html_to_json

html = "your HTML code goes here"
json = html_to_json.convert(html)
print(json)
```

The way that you generate your `html` string depends on the source of HTML: it can come from a file, an url, ...